# SQL select group query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Below is my Table

Table1

```
+--------+----------+---------+  
| amount | make     | product |  
+--------+----------+---------+  
|    100 | Nokia    | Mobiles |   
|    300 | Samesung | Mobiles |   
|    700 | Micromax | Mobiles |   
|   1000 | Karbonn  | Mobiles |   
|    500 | Lava     | Mobiles |   
|    100 | Floyer   | Gift    |   
|    500 | Arichies | Gift    |   
|    300 | Feeling  | Gift    |   
+--------+----------+---------+
```

Now I want to display the two highest amount for each product...

So I want to build single SQL query which gives me result as below..

```
+--------+----------+---------+  
| amount | make     | product |  
+--------+----------+---------+  
|   1000 | Karbonn  | Mobiles |   
|    700 | Micromax | Mobiles |   
|    500 | Arichies | Gift    |   
|    300 | Feeling  | Gift    |   
+--------+----------+---------+
```

Kindly help me to build such query..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this solution to retrieve the "*group-wise maximum*" based on the `amount`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table1 b ON a.product = b.product AND a.amount <= b.amount
GROUP BY a.amount, a.product
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
```

Simply change the `2` to however many of the *top* rows you want to retrieve per product.

If you wanted to retrieve the lowest two rows per product, you can simply change the `<=` sign in the `INNER JOIN` to a `>=`.

You can fiddle around with this solution here: [SQL-Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f273/23/0)

Answer (score 4):

```
select product, make, amount, rnk
from (
  select l.product, l.make, l.amount, count(*) as rnk
  from table1 as l
  left join table1 as r
  on (r.product = l.product and l.amount <= r.amount) 
  group by l.product, l.make
) a
where rnk <= 2
```

see the ideea and other examples here: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/27/simulating-the-sql-row_number-function/

and [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f273/40) based on zane bien test data.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table1 b ON a.product = b.product AND a.amount <= b.amount
GROUP BY a.amount, a.product
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2
ORDER BY a.amount desc
```

Please refer to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ba82/1

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 2 amount, make, product from table1 
where product='Mobiles'
order by amount desc
union
select top 2 amount, make, product from table1 
where product='Gift'
order by amount desc
```

Comment: the answer is not general. What if you have 100 products?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:
1) Add Row Index column that will reflect the order and then select all rows with Row <= 2

```
SELECT amount, make,product
FROM 
(SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [product] ORDER BY [amount] DESC) AS [RowID],*
FROM [dbo].[Table1]) RESULT
WHERE RowID <= 2
```

2) You can also join the table to itself

```
SELECT a1.* FROM Table1 AS a1
  LEFT JOIN Table1 AS a2 
    ON a1.product = a2.product AND a1.amount<= a2.amount
GROUP BY a1.product
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 2;
```

Comment: mysql does not have analytic functions.