# SQL select query help required

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My question is similar to [SQL select Group query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407601/sql-select-group-query). But there is change in schema and I want different result as mentioned below. the solutions of given link doesn't give me the proper solutions. You can use [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdd1a/2) to solve this.

Below is my Table

Table1

```
+--------+----------+---------+  
| amount | make     | product |  
+--------+----------+---------+  
|    100 | Nokia    | Mobiles |   
|    300 | Samesung | Mobiles |   
|    700 | Micromax | Mobiles |   
|   1000 | Karbonn  | Mobiles |   
|    300 | Lava     | Mobiles |   
|    100 | Floyer   | Gift    |   
|    500 | Arichies | Gift    |   
|    300 | Feeling  | Gift    |   
+--------+----------+---------+
```

Now I want to display the two lowest amount for each product and if the amount is same then anyone according to ascending alphabet order of make column...

So I want to build single SQL query which gives me result as below..

```
+--------+----------+---------+  
| amount | make     | product |  
+--------+----------+---------+  
|    100 | Nokia    | Mobiles |   
|    300 | Lava     | Mobiles |   
|    100 | Floyer   | Gift    |   
|    300 | Feeling  | Gift    |   
+--------+----------+---------+
```

Kindly help me to build such query..

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group). Take a look at the accepted answer on this with a [link](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you ..

First one had a bug, it is updated now.

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
    SELECT  @lim := 2,
            @cg := ''
    ) vars,
    (select * from Table1 order by product,amount, make)  t
WHERE   CASE WHEN @cg <> product THEN @r := @lim ELSE 1 END > 0
    AND (@r := @r - 1) >= 0
    AND (@cg := product) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    product,amount, make
```

Have fun with it and with the fiddler : 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdd1a/115/0

Comment: works fine, could u please explain it briefly in q or 2 sentence

Comment: It had a bug, is fine now. Anyway, it's an implementation for row_number() over (partition by .. order by .. of oracle or mssql). A good explanation of how it works you can find here http://explainextended.com/2009/03/05/row-sampling/

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one:

```
select * from table1 ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem of getting 2 rows per group, it would return 2 rows total

Comment: This will only return 2 group, you mistaken the question completely!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT amount, make,product
FROM 
  (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY amount) AS RowID,*
   FROM Table1) RESULT
WHERE RowID <= 2
```

this works well in PostgreSQL, 
mysql doesn't support the window function, by getting work similar windowing function in mysql [refer](http://briansteffens.com/2011/07/19/row_number-partition-and-over-in-mysql/)

Comment: gives the error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY product ORDER BY amount) AS RowID,* FROM Table1) RESULT WHERE R' at line 3: SELECT amount, make,product FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY amount) AS RowID,* FROM Table1) RESULT WHERE RowID <= 2

Comment: yah .. mysql guys should really start implementing the neat stuff on their engines also.