# not all named parameters have been set hibernate in createSQLQuery

Tags: java, hibernate, struts

I am getting the error of **not all named parameters have been set**. Below is my code.

my SqlQuery which is running fine at mysql prompt, You can refer schema in the question [SQL Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595841/sql-select-query-help-required)

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
    SELECT  @lim := 2,
            @cg := ''
    ) vars,
    (select * from Table1 order by product,amount, make)  t
WHERE   CASE WHEN @cg <> product THEN @r := @lim ELSE 1 END > 0
    AND (@r := @r - 1) >= 0
    AND (@cg := product) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    product,amount, make
```

my java code

```
try {
             context.dbl.startTransaction();
             Session session = context.dbl.getSession();

             //String sqlQuery = "from com.infibeam.inventoryservice.dbObjects.PopularBrandDO";
             String sqlQuery = "SELECT  t.* ";
             sqlQuery=sqlQuery + "FROM    (";
             sqlQuery=sqlQuery + "SELECT  @lim := 2,";
             sqlQuery=sqlQuery + "@cg := ''";
             sqlQuery=sqlQuery + ") vars, ";
             sqlQuery=sqlQuery + "(select * from Table1 order by product,amount, make) t";
             sqlQuery=sqlQuery + " WHERE   CASE WHEN @cg <> product THEN @r := @lim ELSE 1 END > 0";
             sqlQuery=sqlQuery + " AND (@r := @r - 1) >= 0 ";
             sqlQuery=sqlQuery + " AND (@cg := product) IS NOT NULL ";
             sqlQuery=sqlQuery + " ORDER BY product,amount, make";
             //Query query = session.createQuery(sqlQuery);
             SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
             listItems = query.list();


            }catch(RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Below is the exception i am getting

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Not all named parameters have been set: [] [SELECT  t.* FROM    (SELECT  @lim := 2,@cg := '') vars, (select * from Table1 order by product,amount, make) t WHERE   CASE WHEN @cg <> product THEN @r := @lim ELSE 1 END > 0 AND (@r := @r - 1) >= 0  AND (@cg := product) IS NOT NULL  ORDER BY product,amount, make]
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.verifyParameters(AbstractQueryImpl.java:291)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.verifyParameters(SQLQueryImpl.java:199)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:143)
    at com.infibeam.weaverbird.helper.PopularBrandFacetHelper.bootstrap(PopularBrandFacetHelper.java:48)
```

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is the assignments with `:=`, which are by the way no standard SQL.

In SQL after a `:` always a parameter is expected, like in `where value = :param` and :param has the be set as a parameter then. Now hibernate is scanning the select and find colons where no set parameters follow.

Solution: Redesign your selection using hibernate standards.

You can use two different HQL queries.

First: Select all product: `select distinct product from Table1`

Second: For each product you do `from Table1 where product = :prod`, :prod you set as a parameter with the actual product, and with setMaxResults(2) you can limit the number of rows as you need.

Now it is many selects and not a single one, but nevertheless they might be faster than the single query (the single query is complicated and risks an inefficient search strategy in the database). And a big advantage, now it is purely HQL and so your program is portable to different databases.